# Advantages of OS-CFAR over CA-CFAR?

Tags: signal-processing, noise, radar-chart

In RADAR signal processing we use Constant False Alram Rate(CFAR) algorithm to identify the target from the background noise.
Most widespread algorithms are

1. Cell Averaging CFAR
2. Ordered Statistics CFAR
   Whats the advantages of OS-CFAR over CA-CFAR?

Answer (score 0):

[ADVANTAGE OF OS-CFAR OVER CA-CFAR]

1. Good for scanning target in multitarget environment
2. Give better result of scanning result ( target and their positions)

[DISADVANTAGE OF OS-CFAR OVER CA-CFAR]

1. The OS-CFAR time process for radar signal processing is longer than CA-CFAR

You can see this journal/link for more information about the comparison between OS-CFAR and CA-CFAR:

1. https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9163697
2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187705091830560X